# Iterações dentro de TransactionScope

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transações

Tenho um projeto Asp.Net MVC com Entity Framework 5.0 em .Net Framework 4.0.

Quais são os prejuízos trazidos por uma `TransactionScope` muito longa?

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
   foreach(var categoria in categorias)
   {
      // Sequencia de instruções
      db.Categoria.Add(categoria);
   }
   foreach(var produto in produtos)
   {
      // Sequencia de instruções
      db.Produto.Add(produto);
   }
   // Sequencia de instruções ou outra iterações.
   db.SaveChanges();
   scope.Complete();
}
```

Ele seria melhorado de alguma forma dividindo em várias Transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Quais são os prejuízos trazidos por uma `TransactionScope` muito longa?

Penalidades de performance, basicamente. Se o escopo da transação ainda pedir *lock* exclusivo, o sistema como um todo fica lento.

> Ele seria melhorado de alguma forma dividindo em várias *Transactions*?

Depende. Se as entidades não possuem correlação, você pode paralelizar. Caso contrário, pelo fato de o contexto não ser *thread-safe*, não é possível paralelizar.

Isto não significa que ficará mais rápido. A paralelização é recomendada para volumes grandes de dados. Para transações pequenas, a diferença de performance não é muito sentida.

Outra coisa que você pode fazer é usar métodos assíncronos, que melhoram a concorrência entre requisições, mas você terá que ir para o .NET 4.5 e Entity Framework 6:

```
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled)) // Só no .NET 4.5 em diante dá pra fazer isso
{
   foreach(var categoria in categorias)
   {
      // Sequencia de instruções
      db.Categoria.Add(categoria);
   }
   foreach(var produto in produtos)
   {
      // Sequencia de instruções
      db.Produto.Add(produto);
   }
   // Sequencia de instruções ou outra iterações.
   await db.SaveChangesAsync();
   scope.Complete();
}
```