# Transaction com múltiplas consultas

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transações

Eu estava visualizando [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134011/48346), e para tentar responder decidi realizar alguns testes onde pude constatar o seguinte problema:

Ao realizar múltiplas consultas ao Banco de Dados via **Entity Framework** dentro de uma única `TransactionScope` recebo o seguinte erro:

> O servidor subjacente falhou em Open

Fui atrás de respostas e encontrei [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3081776/4720858), onde o autor diz:

"Se você estiver usando o Entity Framework com transações, o Entity Framework automaticamente abre e fecha uma conexão com cada chamada de banco de dados. Então, quando estiver usando transações, você está tentando espalhar uma transação ao longo de várias conexões. Isso eleva para MSDTC." - Tradução livre.

Logo imaginei que eu poderia em determinado trecho do meu código (antes de uma segunda consulta) verificar o estado da conexão e reabri-la, da seguinte forma:

```
if (context.Database.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
    context.Database.Connection.Open();
}
```

Mas infelizmente o resultado não saiu como o esperado, pois um novo erro foi exibido ao tentar abrir a conexão:

> O acesso à rede do Gerenciador de Transações Distribuídas (MSDTC) foi desabilitado. Habilite o acesso à rede do DTC na configuração de segurança do MSDTC usando a ferramenta Administrativa dos Serviços de Componentes.

Por que esse recurso é necessário?
Esse recurso está no lado do cliente ou do servidor?
Ao fazer o deploy da minha aplicação para o servidor oficial terei que habilitar algo lá? (Meu servidor da aplicação está separado do servidor de banco de dados)

Existe alguma solução alternativa? (Realizar múltiplas ações em uma única transaction)

Trecho do código:

```
using (MeuEntities context = new MeuEntities())
{
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        int ordemAlternativa = 1;

        if (questaoAlternativa.RespostaCorreta == true)
        {
            var alternativasDaQuestao = context.QuestaoAlternativa.Where(qa => qa.QuestaoId == questaoAlternativa.QuestaoId);
            if (alternativasQuestao != null && alternativasQuestao.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in alternativasQuestao)
                {
                    item.RespostaCorreta = false;
                    context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }

                ordemAlternativa = alternativasQuestao.Max(qa => qa.Prioridade == null ? 1 : (qa.Prioridade + 1));
            }
        }

        questaoAlternativa.Prioridade = ordemAlternativa;
        context.QuestaoAlternativa.Add(questaoAlternativa);

        // Código adicional para reabrir conexão
        if (context.Database.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            context.Database.Connection.Open();
        }

        // Erro ao realizar consulta
        int prioridadeArquivo = context.QuestaoAlternativaImagem.DefaultIfEmpty().Max(qai => qai.Prioridade == null ? 0 : qai.Prioridade);

        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            prioridadeArquivo++;

            byte[] fileData = new byte[Request.Files[i].InputStream.Length];
            Request.Files[i].InputStream.Read(fileData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(Request.Files[i].InputStream.Length));
            QuestaoAlternativaImagem questaoAlternativaImagem = new QuestaoAlternativaImagem() { NomeArquivo = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[i].FileName), Descricao = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[i].FileName), Prioridade = prioridadeArquivo, Imagem = fileData, QuestaoAlternativaId = questaoAlternativa.QuestaoAlternativaId, Guid = Guid.NewGuid() };
            context.QuestaoAlternativaImagem.Add(questaoAlternativaImagem);
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Esse seria um modelo alternativo? http://stackoverflow.com/a/794785/4720858 criando assim vários `DbContext` e dando `SaveChanges()` pra cada bloco, todos eles dentro de um único `TransactionScope`.

Comment: Quais "múltiplas consultas" você realizou?

Comment: vou acrescentar o código na pergunta.

Comment: aproveitei um código do meu projeto que eu estava curioso pra implementar isso.

Comment: Não tem nada de errado com o código. O problema é outro.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade o problema não é este. [Você apenas não habilitou o suporte ao coordenador de transações, cujos passos estão aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16327/transactionscope-n%C3%A3o-efetua-transa%C3%A7%C3%B5es/16330#16330).

O código está quase inteiro certo. Falta só tirar isto:

```
    // Código adicional para reabrir conexão
    if (context.Database.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        context.Database.Connection.Open();
    }
```

Comment: muito obrigado por sua resposta. Mas por que transações mais simples funcionam perfeitamente? Vi na sua resposta lincada que existem alternativas diferentes, mas qual a utilidade desse coordenador? Devo habilita-lo no servidor de aplicação ou de banco de dados?

Comment: Quanto menor o nível de aninhamento de transações, mais simples fica para o coordenador de transações controlar o fluxo de persistência. O coordenador de transações intermedia o fluxo da de persistência da aplicação com o banco de dados. Ele tira de você, programador, a responsabilidade de abrir os cursores de transação. A habilitação é feita no servidor de aplicação.

Comment: Transações muito complexas podem gerar algum tipo de lock?

Comment: Que estranho @CiganoMorrisonMendez não habilitei o suporte ao coordenador de transações e me certifiquei que ele não está em execução, então apenas alterei o **timeout** da transaction e funcionou: `TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions();` `options.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1200);` `using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress, options))`

Comment: Te respondendo, podem sim. Procure não fazer transações muito grandes.

Comment: Possivelmente você pode ter algum gargalo de I/O para ter que usar o *timeout*, mas bom que funcionou. Experimente provocar uma exceção no meio para ver o *rollback* funcionando.